# How does the `OR` operator differ in table requirements to the `AND` operator?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This may seem like a rather basic question but I can't seem to understand the issue with the first screenshot query. Is there a fundamental difference in how `AND` and `OR` operate on data within a table that stipulates a different set of requirements? The second query shows the same conditions but using an `AND` and works fine:

[image: Failed desired query using <code>OR</code>]

[image: Successful undesired query using <code>AND</code>]

Comment: This is rather an issue with partitioning. The `or` query prevents that there is **always** a condition to get the right partition.

Comment: @juergend So is `OR` just unusable with partitioned tables? Is there a common work around?

Comment: The DB wants you to include in your `where` clause some of the columns that are used to determine which partition should be used. But the `or` prevents that. Now the DB can not say which partition to use. I think you did not get the `where` clause right. Are you aware of *operator precedence*? You should add some parentheses in your where clause to make obvious what you want to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses:

```
where (_PARTITIONTIME >= @A and
       _PARTITIONTIME <= @B
      ) and
      (raw like @C or
       raw like @D and raw not like @E
      )
```

Your query is parsed as:

```
where (_PARTITIONTIME >= @A and
       _PARTITIONTIME <= @B
       raw like @C
      ) or
      (
       raw like @D and raw not like @E
      )
```

In this version the partitioning does not apply to the last condition, because of how the conditions are evaluated.

Comment: This worked thanks, useful to know the logic of partition condition application.

Answer (score 0):

By not using parentheses correctly you incur a error.
Using 'AND' does not get you any errors because of the others 'AND's'.

Make sure you use them correctly, or even if you fix the bug, you will still have an result that isn't what you want.